# affordable CDN alternative with mobile detection

Tags: cdn

I have been looking for an affordable CDN alternative for quite some time (researching / contacting all big CDN companies). But I have not found a good affordable alternative yet.

#### CDN criteria

- (Near) **instant purge**
- **HTTPS** for up to 30 domains
- Support for [**Vary**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary): Switch cache based on `User-Agent` mobile/desktop without redirect
- Affordable (near) **instant invalidation** (± 1.000.000 URLs monthly)

  - Ideally: **cache tagging** for specific invalidation
- **Under 500 USD** monthly for 500.000 requests and 2 TB traffic.

#### CDNs not meeting criteria

I've contacted these CDNs already; they do not meet the criteria:

- **Cloudfront**

  - Invalidating URL's is very expensive
  - No instant purge
- **Stackpath**

  - Claims to support dynamic serving; does not actually support it
- **KeyCDN**

  - Claims to support dynamic serving; does not actually support it

#### CDNs meeting technical criteria

These CDNs do meet the criteria, but are too expensive with the criteria combined:

- **Fastly**

  - Over our budget of 500 USD monthly

So in short: **What is a good affordable CDN alternative?**

Answer (score 0):

PageCDN might work for you.

1. Less than 15 seconds purge time. Mostly less than 5 seconds.
2. No CNAME hosts. Primary host is `pagecdn.io` that serves all of your content.
3. PageCDN does not require you to create expensive zones. You can create zones easily with API and mix it with device detection performed at the origin server. This will give you workable alternative of `Vary`. Allowing full support for Vary header is very expensive at CDN level.
4. If you need instant invalidation, you should try pagecdn's builtin path based cache busters. Contrary to the cache busting usually deployed at the origin servers, this is resolved at file level at pagecdn.
5. Same as point 4. You can use cache busters for tags.
6. 500USD plan will give you 15 TB bandwidth and you can work with 500 origins (still more than 30 origins * 15 useragent variations).

In addition, you also get:

1. Github pull.
2. Free Public CDN.
3. Configurable compression. Even Brotli-11 compression is support.
4. Configurable Edge and HTTP Cache Age. Immutable Caching is also supported.
5. Configurable HTTP/2 Server Push.